# hPlot pie chart - show percentage in tooltip instead of absolute values

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I'm using hPlot of type = pie. I want the tooltip to show the percent from total instead of the absolute value.
I tried to use the following code:

```
piechart<<- hPlot(x = "item", y = "total_purchase", 
               data = as.data.frame(items_purchased), type = "pie") 
 piechart$tooltip(formatter = "#! function() {return(point.percentage:.1f %);} !#")
```

but now the whole pie chart doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello check this example :

```
dat <- data.frame(
  VAR1 = letters[1:5],
  FREQ = c(145, 784, 562, 258, 348)
)

library("rCharts")
hpie <- Highcharts$new()
hpie$chart(
  type = "pie"
)
hpie$plotOptions(
  pie = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %')
  )
)
hpie$series(
  name = "Example", 
  data = toJSONArray2(obj = dat, json = FALSE, names = FALSE)
)
hpie$tooltip(
  formatter = "#!function() {return this.point.name + ' : <b>' + this.y + ' (' + Math.round(this.percentage) + '%)<b>'}!#"
)
hpie
```

In the tooltip's formatter you should use `this.percentage` instead of `point.percentage`.

Comment: Maybe you could use Highcharts.formatNumber instead of Math.round, it is more flexible. See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat